# Где задается ip адрес в linux?

Tags: linux, сеть, системное-программирование

Структура net_device содержит в себе информацию о сетевых интерфейсах, там я не нашёл поле для ip(может плохо смотрел),я так понимаю он где то выше прикрепляется к буферу. Написано что у сетевого интерфейса должен быть ip, но тут получается можно инициализировать устройство без ip.

Comment: У одного устройства может быть несколько ip адресов. И да, устройство может работать без ip адреса. Так что да, ip явно где то отдельно, уже на уровне стека ip, а не устройств. Не даром утилита командной сроки 'ip' явно разделяет link и addr

Comment: А тогда интересно кто реализует в ОС работу c ip, сетевой уровень, это в папке /net?

Comment: Реализация протокола IPv4 в папке `/net/ipv4`, протокола IPv6 в папке `/net/ipv6`. Адрес привязан  к структуре `struct in_device`, поле `inf_list`. Структура определена в заголовочном файле `include/linux/inetdevice.h`

Comment: Сорри, поле в структуре `ina_list`

Comment: @PakUula то есть уже обработка пакета будет на уровне протокола, которые в /net, и драйвер сетевого устройства к этому отношению не имеет? то есть обработка пакета и его маршрутизация происходит в модуле ядра, а не на уровне драйвера?

Comment: Конечно. задача драйвера сетевого устройства работать с самим устройством. Это на канальном уровне модели OSI. Его не интересует, что за данные и каких протоколов сетевого уровня OSI он передает. Ведь он может работать и не с протоколом IP, а с кучей других

Comment: @Mike  еще вопрос и пазл сложится, во всех источниках пишется, что сетевой интерфейс должен быть инициализирован ip адресом,  это имеется ввиду для протокола ip?  Он же может быть и без ip.

Comment: @Venot Странные источники. Они не правы. Достаточно дать `ifconfig интерфейс UP` или `ip link dev интерфейс set up` и устройство поднимается. И им даже уже можно пользоваться, например запустить на нем tcpdump для просмотра трафика, Отлично будет работать. А при использовании 802.1Q vlan например на интерфейс цепляются эти самые vlan (`vconfig`), которые сами по себе интерфейсы и на основное устройство при этом дается UP и никакого ip, потому что там ходят не сами ip пакеты, а пакеты с заголовком 802.1q который ставится вообще перед полем типа enernet протокола.